# Is there any way to print console output dynamically in a html page?

Tags: java

I try to create a system like "deploy in one button".That means when i click some button my services (docker image) begins to be deployed in server.I want to show the deploy process (console output) in the html page.Any good way to do this? Thx

Comment: Do you need to implement that from scratch? Can't you use Jenkins or a similar tool?

Comment: If you want dynamic web pages, you need Javascript, not just Java

Comment: sry but i am not familiar with those but i'll check that . thx @LuiggiMendoza